# Distribute .net COM got 0x80070002 message

Tags: vb.net, com

I distributed a .net COM to client machines. All machines work except one XP machine.

It got 0x80070002 message when try to create an object from the COM component.

The machine has an older version of the same component which works ok.

For the new version, I just generate a new set of GUIDs and add some new function to the program.

I have been trying to uninstall both versions and only install the new version. However, I still got the problem.

Is anybody know what's possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: If is "File not found", about the most common error.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility, you'll see it searching for the file and not finding it.  Where it looks ought to be a clue to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that error code translates to 'Cannot find the specified file'. I would check that any and all dependencies/references required by your dll are installed on the target machine, including the correct version of the .Net framework that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. More comment on this issue. I use same development tool for both new and old version. So I think the new version should have same dependent set of files as the old one. And the old one works fine. Any other possible reason?